# How can I store raw input into a variable and then pass that variable into another script without requesting input again?

Tags: python

Basically what I am trying to do is store raw input into a variable and then call that variable in another script. However, when I do this the second script asks for the input again. Is there a way to save the input in the variable without requesting the input in the second script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def userInput():

    token = raw_input('Enter your Spark Token: ')
    member = raw_input('Enter your email:')

    return token and member
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you're calling both scripts separately from the command line?  If so, why not import this script into the second one, and call the `userInput()` function from there directly?  Please clarify what you've already tried, and what exact functionality you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Try to use modules and packages - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Can you share your second script?

Comment: Thank you guys, jegesh - I did this and it works well. I guess I was hoping to basically make a script that gathers all of my user input variables and then a separate script that can use those variables. I am trying to keep them separate so that the code is reusable, but I am new and do not know the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I've understood correctly your question but you could try this:

> main.py

```
from bar import user_input

def foo():
    token, member = user_input()
    print "Login user {0} with token {1}".format(member, token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
```

> bar.py

```
def user_input():
    token = raw_input('Enter your Spark Token: ')
    member = raw_input('Enter your email:')

    return token, member
```

As you can see, in the file `main.py` you're calling your `bar.user_input` method once so you'll get asked by member & token only once.